# UIImage with NSData - image compression dependancy

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsdata

I understand the need of image compression while downloading images when connected to a 3G network, but I am getting really bad looking images... I'm caching downloaded images and I realized that the quality of the images depends on the active connection. My code:

```
        KTMember *member = [[DataManager sharedManager] getMemberWithId:memberId];
    if (member) {
        NSLog(@"caching member %d locally",member.memberId);
        memberImg = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:member.imageUrl]]];
        [[DataManager sharedManager] saveImageToDocuments:memberImg withId:memberId];
        return memberImg;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
```

So the question is - is there any way of overriding the image compression even though the active network is 3G?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global mechanism that adaptively increases image compression for slow connections. What you describe would require custom code on the server, and would vary from server to server.

What service is providing these images?

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I am downloading jpeg images from static URLs, this could hardly be considered as a "service", I think. Maybe some third party app is causing this? weird...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Thank you for fixing my answer, There are some mechanism of image compressing by Verizon network optimization.

I think,The quality of image, in the term of byte stream, depend on the server provide whether or not compression.

But there is some solution. you can also implement `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` to handle the data from URL request with Thread Programming. There is interesting method :

```
/** connection:didReceiveResponse: is called when
 *               enough data has been read to construct an
 *               NSURLResponse object. In the event of a protocol
 *               which may return multiple responses (such as HTTP
 *               multipart/x-mixed-replace) the delegate should be
 *               prepared to inspect the new response and make
 *               itself ready for data callbacks as appropriate.
 **/

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

/** connection:didReceiveData: is called with a single
  *              immutable NSData object to the delegate,
  *              representing the next portion of the data loaded
  *              from the connection.  This is the only guaranteed
  *              for the delegate to receive the data from the
  *              resource load
  **/

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

/** connection:willCacheResponse: gives the delegate
  *              an opportunity to inspect and modify the
  *              NSCachedURLResponse which will be cached by the
  *              loader if caching is enabled for the original
  *              NSURLRequest.  Returning nil from this delegate
  *              will prevent the resource from being cached.  Note
  *              that the -data method of the cached response may
  *              return an autoreleased in-memory copy of the true
  *              data, and should not be used as an alternative to
  *              receiving and accumulating the data through
  *              connection:didReceiveData
  **/

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse;

/** connectionDidFinishLoading: is called when all
  *              connection processing has completed successfully,
  *              before the delegate is released by the
  *              connection
  **/

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

You can also manage your data in `didReceiveData` with accumulate each incoming data and when complete downloading , In `connectionDidFinishLoading` , you could deal with the `NSData` of image that you receive all.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: There have been reports that Verizon recompresses images over 3G. See http://support.verizonwireless.com/information/data_disclosure.html via http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1165293

Comment: Interesting. That post only mentions video optimization, however, not still image optimization. As an app developer that sort of optimization would be maddening, if you're delivering content for semi-permanent storage and re-use.